# Hibernate generates a "on ... and null=null" on left join

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpql

Enviroment:

- hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final
- PostgreSQL 9.3.5

I execute current this JPQL query

```
select distinct entity
from Incidence entity
  left join treat(entity.road as Road) as road
where entity.road is not null and lower(road.nomenclature) like :value
```

looking on log file, this generate this query for PostgreSQL:

```
select
distinct 
....
....
from public.incidence incidence0_ 
left outer join public.road road1_ 
    on incidence0_.road=road1_.id and null=null 
where (incidence0_.road is not null)  and (lower(road1_.nomenclature) like ? )
```

Using `%cv%` as parameter, this query should return 175 rows, but  I get none.

If I run the query commenting the `and null=null` on PostgreSQL I get the expected result:

```
select
distinct 
....
....
from public.incidence incidence0_ 
left outer join public.road road1_ 
    on incidence0_.road=road1_.id /* and null=null */
where (incidence0_.road is not null)  and (lower(road1_.nomenclature) like '%cv%' )
```

So... Why hibernate adds the  "null=null" condition to left join?

I've tried it with Oracle and I got the very same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several proofs I found that the problems is about the use of `treat` expression.

From JPA 2.1 specification: *4.4.9 Downcasting*:

> ...
>
> If the target type is not a subtype (proper or improper) of the static type of the first argument, the query is invalid.

In my model, *Road* is a entity class without supper class and has no subtype, so, as I can understand, my JPQL **should throw an exception or (as is the same type) ignore the *treat* expression**

I've created a [Jira request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9395) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `entity.road is not null` try using directly your alias `road`

```
select distinct entity
from Incidence entity
left join treat(entity.road as Road) as road
where road is not null and      lower(road.nomenclature) like :value
```

Because when you use entity.road Hibernate tries to add an implicit join and in your case it probably becomes mixed up between your left join and it's own implicit join.

Also why not use directly a `join` instead of a `left join` if you only want `Incidence` having a `Road` with a specific `nomenclature` value

Comment: After several proofs I found that the problems is about the use of `treat` expression. I've created a [Jira request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9395) about it. Thank you anyway.